# Como ajusta minha data da minha query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```html
$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE DATE(date_created) = '$data' AND 
tipo_venda = '$tipo_vendas' AND tipo = '$tipo_pagamento' ORDER BY 'id'";
```

Tenho essa query, mas a mesma não funcionar direito pois o input que preencher a variável '$data' vem com o formato '12/11/2018' e o formato que conta na colona 'date_created' e '2018-12-11', como faço pra ajusta a minha query??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem várias formas de fazer isso. Recomendo o seguinte:

```
// Recebe a variável com a data, e cria um objeto DateTime a partir do formato especificado.
$objetoData = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);

// Reformata a data do jeito desejado
$data = $objetoData->format('Y-m-d');
```

Depois é só usar a variável `$data` da forma que você estava fazendo.

Answer (score 6):

Use uma função que irá servir para duas entradas `dd/mm/YYYY ou YYYY-mm-dd`.

```
function inverteData($data){
    if(count(explode("/",$data)) > 1){
        return join("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$data)));
    }elseif(count(explode("-",$data)) > 1){
        return join("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$data)));
    }
}

$data = "12/11/2018";

//para usar na query
$dataInvertida = inverteData($data); //2018-11-12

//alguma data retornada do select
$dataBanco = "2018-11-21";

$dataBancoInvertida =  inverteData($dataBanco); // 21/11/2018
```

exemplo no [ideone](https://ideone.com/7xRL4N)

```
$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE DATE(date_created) = '$dataInvertida' AND 
tipo_venda = '$tipo_vendas' AND tipo = '$tipo_pagamento' ORDER BY 'id'";
```

Answer (score 4):

Já que você precisa apenas fazer a consulta, pode trazer a sua coluna `date_created` do select formatado como precisa.

```
DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%d/%m/%y')
```

[Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) tem maiores informações sobre a função `date_format`

---

É possivel fazer através do PHP também.

Transformando a data que você recebe no padrão utilizado pelo BD.

```
$dataFormat = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
```

E para utilizar depois você pode formatar ela para o padrão necessário

```
$data = $dataFormat->format('Y-m-D');
```